# Is seeing console.log on client expected for SSR? (Next JS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-ssr

I've created a simple page to test SSR implementation. There is one thing I couldn't be sure. If you could help to understand would be great!

```
const EmptyPage = () => {
  console.log("rendered !!!");
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <span>/empty-page-with-next</span>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  return {};
}

export default EmptyPage;
```

If I open the page, I see that **rendered !!!** on the server and client(browser's console) both.

I was expecting not to see that on the client.. Is that normal to see it? There is no use-effect, no trigger to re-render the page..?

Comment: This is expected. The render on the server is a *pre-render* to build the initial HTML. It will always render again on the client.